# How to add csrf token to the html form?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

After I enabled csrf(removed line `.csrf().disable()`) in my application my login request stopped working - `/login` `POST` redirects me to the home page:

request looks like this:
[image]

On the page I have following js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/js-cookie/js.cookie.js"></script>
...
$('#login-form').submit(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
    var headerName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";
    var token = Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
    $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', '_csrf').attr('value', Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')).appendTo('#login-form');
    this.submit(); // If all the validations succeeded
    })
```

Can you clarify what am doing wrong?

### P.S.

I read a lot of related stuff and everywhere I found lines like this:

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

I don't understand how should I set value `_csrf.headerName`

I tried to add these data to meta bit its doesn't resolve:
[image]

and I tried to add it to the form directly:

[image]

And no success again.

Additionally i tried this:

[image]

But as you can see - it doesn't resolve my attributes too

### P.S.2

configuration:

```
EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String SECURE_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "rockandroll";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/index.html")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/sender.html")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/js/**", "/lib/**", "/images/**", "/css/**", "/index.html", "/","/*.css","/webjars/**", "/*.js").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/websocket").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider() {

            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
                return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
            }

            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;

                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = SECURE_ADMIN_PASSWORD.equals(token.getCredentials()) ?
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN") : null;

                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token.getName(), token.getCredentials(), authorities);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-messaging-stomp-websocket'
    version = '0.1.0'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket")
    compile("org.webjars:webjars-locator-core")
    compile("org.webjars:sockjs-client:1.0.2")
    compile("org.webjars:stomp-websocket:2.3.3")
    compile("org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.7")
    compile("org.webjars:jquery:3.1.0")
    compile("org.webjars:js-cookie:2.1.0")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    //security
    compile ('org.springframework.security:spring-security-messaging')
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config'

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

Comment: Ok, I can see U added more info. I'd like to ask you to add more details about what error you are getting (or what behavior you expect but it does not work that way).

Comment: Do you use server template language JSP or Thymeleaf?

Comment: @holmis83 I use raw html

Comment: @john Result the same).  **/login** responds 302 instead of successful login. Login happens successfuly in case of I disable csrf explicitly(**.csrf().disable()**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried different ways and eventually I've found the solution:

Previously `index.html` was located in the folder `/resources/static`

I put it in the folder `/resources/templates`. Also I've added dependency:

```
compile('org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5');
```

and explicitly declared the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(){
   return "index";
}
```

`index.html` look like this:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="springChat" xmlns:th="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
<head>
    ...
    <meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta name="_csrf_parameter_name" th:content="${_csrf.parameterName}"/>

....
</body>     
<script type="application/javascript">

    $('#login-form').submit(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
        var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        var paramName = $("meta[name='_csrf_parameter_name']").attr("content");
        $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', paramName).attr('value', token).appendTo('#login-form');

        this.submit(); 
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Looks like spring boot searches in `/resources/static` raw html if we don't have explicitly declared mapping and doesn't try to insert values like `th:content="${_csrf.token}"` into variables.

Comment: thanks! just to get attention th: is very important prefix here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this input to your form directly (not with jQuery):

```
<form>
    <!-- all the rest inputs -->

    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

If you send your data to the server via AJAX, you can obtain those values from your `<meta>`s.

```
$(function () {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });
});
```

If in your case you need to persist the `CsrfToken` in a cookie, by default the `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` will write to a cookie named `XSRF-TOKEN` and read it from a header named `X-XSRF-TOKEN` or the HTTP parameter `_csrf`.

Comment: I use raw html so I can't use it

Comment: This solution works, but do you know why in a jsp form we  can send that a form data, but when we are doing Ajax we need to add it as a header instead of form data in body? Confusing